# How to make a nested msi in InstallShield 2014 express

Tags: installshield

I have 2 .msi files, say a.msi and b.msi.
I need to chain these two msi files together. I need a wrapper program which starts installation of a.msi file first. Once it is completed installation of b.msi should start.

I installed InstallShield express 2014 to do this task. But articles show that it needs a commercial version of InstallShield is needed. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

InstallShield Express is commercial, so perhaps you meant the Limited Edition. Regardless, short of creating a Suite Project in InstallShield Premier, you really shouldn't try to chain MSIs files together.

If one of those two files is a prerequisite rather than a component, you can look into the prerequisite support. The prerequisite editor is available in the Professional and higher editions; prerequisites themselves are usable in lower editions.